# When building layered jars in Spring Boot, how do you include a multi-module projects jars in a layer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

According to the [Spring Boot gradle plugin reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable), I should be able to package a particular pattern of jars into a specific layer (for making better docker files).

I'm confused about the pattern matching used in the documentation. Here's an example:

```
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    layered {
        isIncludeLayerTools = true
        application {
            intoLayer("spring-boot-loader") {
                include("org/springframework/boot/loader/**")
            }
            intoLayer("application")
        }
        dependencies {

            intoLayer("module-dependencies") {
                include("com*:*:*")
            }

            intoLayer("dependencies")
        }
        layerOrder = listOf("dependencies", "spring-boot-loader", "module-dependencies", "application")
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is what this pattern matching is matching on:

intoLayer("module-dependencies") {
include("com*:*:*")
}

Is it the group, artifact and version of a jar ? Is it the name of the jar ?

If I have a multi-module project that has modules aa,ab and ac, equating to aa.jar, ab.jar and ac.jar and an external dependency org.something:anartifact:25 equating to anartifact-25.jar what pattern do I need to add to include aa,ab and ac in one layer and every other dependency in another layer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For module dependencies the pattern is `<group>:<artifactid>:<version>`. You can using trailing wildcard to match a subset of items or omit the item entirely to match everything. For example, `com.fasterxml.jackson::` will match all artifact and all versions in the `com.fasterxml.jackson` group.

In the case of a multi-module project, by default the `artifactid` is the name of the project and the `group` is the value of the `group` value set in your `build.gradle`.

It's usually common to define the group in the root project's `build.gradle` file, for example:

```
allprojects {
  group "com.example"
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

You can then define the layer patterns as follows in your application module:

```
bootJar {
    layered {
        application {
            intoLayer("spring-boot-loader") {
                include("org/springframework/boot/loader/**")
            }
            intoLayer("application")
        }
        dependencies {
            intoLayer("module-dependencies") {
                include("com.example:*:*")
            }
            intoLayer("dependencies")
        }
        layerOrder = [ "dependencies", "spring-boot-loader", "module-dependencies", "application" ]
    }
}
```

I've uploaded a sample to https://github.com/philwebb/mutli-module-layered-gradle-example that shows this in a complete project.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks - my error was not having the group set in allprojects and not getting the pattern syntax. Using dive to have a look at my image now shows a 6 meg layer for the module-dependencies, nicely separated from the external dependencies. Thanks again.